# How can I get the closed interval of a given function using W. Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I get the closed interval of a given function using Wolfram Mathematica?

f(x)= 3+2x-x^2

Comment: What is the closed interval? The function's domain, codomain?

Comment: The upper and lower bound.

Comment: Context: I need to get the area of the function, but before that, I need to get the closed interval(upper and lower bound) of the function to integrate. I need to show in Wolfram Mathematica how I got the closed interval.

Comment: Dear @KevinSneaks, perhaps you want to calculate the area under the function that lies above the $x$-axis? Since `Solve[3+2*x-x^2==0,x]` gives `{{x->-1},{x->3}}` (you may also want to use `Plot[3+2*x-x^2,{x,-2,4}]`) you have to integrate over the interval $-1 \leq x \leq 3$. Please note however that "closed interval of a given function" is not standard math terminology.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: `f[x_] = 3 + 2 x - x^2; Reduce[f[x] >= 0, x]`

Answer (score 2):

Your function is:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] := 3 + 2 x - x^2

Plot[
  f[x], {x, -3, 5}, 
  Mesh -> {{0.}}, MeshFunctions -> {3 + 2 # - #^2 &},
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Red],
  Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, {None, Automatic}}}
]
```

[image: plot of inverted parabola, with zeroes at x=-1 and x=3 as red points, and portion between x axis and function filled in]

If you want to calculate the area highlighted in the plot above, i.e. between the horizontal axis and the portion of the function that is positive and bounded, then you can take multiple approaches.

On the one hand you can explicitly find the zeroes of the function and then integrate between them:

```
Reduce[f[x] == 0, x]
(* Out: x == -1 || x == 3 *)

Integrate[f[x], {x, -1, 3}]
(* Out: 32/3 *)
```

An alternative would be to let MMA do all the work, by integrating a function that has the value of your $f(x)$ where $f(x)\geq 0$, and zero elsewhere. We can build that with [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html):

```
Integrate[
  Piecewise[{{f[x], f[x] >= 0}}],
  {x, -Infinity, Infinity}
]

(* Out: 32/3 *)
```